# Firebase Auth not loading persisted user from local storage

Tags: firebase, vue.js, authentication, firebase-authentication, local-storage

I'm using Firebase Auth in a Vue app. I want signed-in users to be persisted through reloading and closing the browser, so I'm using the 'local' persistence setting, which saves logged-in user tokens into the browser's localStorage.

The docs state that Firebase will automatically detect this localStorage entry, and publish a change in auth state, which fires onAuthStateChange handlers.

However, in my app the user credential is not being retrieved after a refresh.

The token is stored properly and can be viewed in the dev tools, so the browserLocalPersistence is working.

When I reload the page, however, the onAuthStateChange hook fires only one time, printing that the current user is null.

#### Code

##### Firebase init

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = initializeAuth(app);
setPersistence(auth, browserLocalPersistence)
```

##### Pinia store w/ action to update state:

```js
export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
    id: "auth",
    state: (): UserState => ({
        user: null,
    }),
    actions: {
        init() {
            return new Promise<User | null>((resolve, reject) => {
                onAuthStateChanged(
                    getAuth(firebaseApp),
                    async (user) => {
                        console.log(user);
                        this.user = user;
                        resolve(user);
                    },
                    reject
                );
            });
        },
    },
});
```

##### Initializing onAuthStateChanged hook within Pinia store from setup function of top-level Vue component:

```js
const authStore = useAuthStore();
authStore.init().then(console.log);
```

With this code, I'm getting `null` printed to the console. That's understandable upon immediate page load, before Firebase has verified the persisted authentication, but I would expect the callback to fire a second time with the correct credentials loaded.

Everything works properly after an initial sign in -- it's only after a refresh that the credentials are not loaded from local storage.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: i'm having this issue too. the setPersistence method returns a promise. I think this is where the issue starts